# Tracking FB Likes in an iframe - the event is not triggering

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Our service allows any company to run a promotion for their business.

Users setup a promotion, copy a snippet of code, and place it on their website which displays the promotion in an iframe.

The promotion page has the Facebook like button embedded and when clicked, it will automatically 'like' that company's facebook page.

We want to track these clicks and display them for our users in their dashboard so they can see how many new 'likes' a promotion brings them.

We tried using the FB.Event.subscribe but the event is not triggering when clicking the like button. We're really new to using FB SDK so we're probably missing something... Here is what we have:

```
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '424426844274364', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//www.viralsweep.com/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
        function(response) {
            alert('You FB liked the URL: ' + response);
        }
    );


    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
```

Comment: How did you embed the like button? The event is only triggered when you use the HTML%/XFBML version of the like button – _not_ if you are using the iframe embedding method.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to load the sdk.js

```
<script src ="https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js" ></script>
```

then you call the function

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
        function(response) {
            alert('You FB liked the URL: ' + response);
        }
    );
```

right now, since the function is called before sdk is being loaded it is not able to find the FB object.